# Find Relevent Result Even it have Long Value Sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Let Supppose I Have String in database

```
Indian Apple(Kashmir) 30Kg at 3400
```

Now i wants to get data relevent to `Indian Apple(Kashmir)` So How Can i get ?

For that i tried

```
SELECT * FROM product where id='1' && name LIKE '%Indian Apple(Kashmir) 30Kg at 3400'
```

But it does not give me proper result So How can i get. And as well as i also tried `name LIKE '%Indian Apple(Kashmir) 30Kg at 3400%'`

For Checking You mAy Run your ideas At **[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_like_ending)**

Comment: In your link `&&` is throwing an error, you may want to replace it with `AND` (although mySQL should accept `&&` according to documentation)

Comment: So I need id because there are many products and what if some product named with same ??

Comment: `id` sounds like its a primary key. If it is, and you add it to your where you can never have more than one row, because there is only one row with that id. I don't really follow your last comment, can you expand on that?

Comment: ohh sorry ..... Thanks Thank you soooooo much@HoneyBadger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now i wants to get data relevent to Indian Apple(Kashmir) So How Can i get ?

I think you want:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product p
WHERE name LIKE '%Indian Apple(Kashmir)%';
```

You probably don't want to select a particular id, if you want to match on the name.

Comment: I Tried that too . Its not working and id is for double confirmation

Comment: Adn You take Only `Indian Apple(Kashmir)`. Please Check What String i Have .